# Flask-SQLAlchemy Foreign Key linking

Tags: python, flask

Hi! I'm trying to link two tables: users and posts together with a foreign key constraint in Flask using Flask-SQLAlchemy. However, when I try to create a new instance of the User class, i get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between pa
rent/child tables on relationship User.posts - there are no foreign keys linking
 these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey
 or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

Here's is the relevant code snippet:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

I'm aware that there are other posts on the site discussing the same exception, but none of the solutions seem to work in my case. Thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: Is ForeignKey('user.id') a typo? Should be 'users.id'.

Comment: Oh, that solved the problem. Thank you very much, I wasted a whole morning trying to solve the problem without noticing this typo :/